# How to freeze panes of output worksheet

Tags: ms-access, vba

I currently have some VBA code written in Access to output an Excel file. Right now, there is no formatting assigned to the spreadsheet, only the raw data that is pulled using the query I created. My questions is, how do I go about freezing the top row of the outputted spreadsheet? See my code below.

```
    Option Compare Database
    Public TimeStamp As String
    Public TimeStamp2 As String

    Function DailyMTDMail()

    If Weekday(Date) = 7 Or Weekday(Date) = 1 Then
    'do nothing
    Else

    TimeStamp = Month(Date) & "." & Day(Date) & "." & Year(Date)


    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "001 Extract Sales in Period", 
    acFormatXLSX, "\\xxx\xxx\xxx\MTD Sales @ " & TimeStamp & ".xlsx", False

    Dim filename As String

    filename = "\\xxx\xxx\xxx\MTD Sales @ " & TimeStamp & ".xlsx"

    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("001 Extract Sales in Period")         ' change to 
    the name of your sheet

    wb.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    ws.Range("a2").Select                ' change to the range you want to 
    freeze

    wb.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    wb.Save
    Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    objMessage.Subject = " Inc - MTD Sales @ " & TimeStamp

    objMessage.From = "email@email.com"

    'objMessage.To = "email@email.com"
    objMessage.To = "email@email.com"    'test


    objMessage.Textbody = "Please find attached MTD sales @ " & TimeStamp & 
    vbCr & vbCr & "Regards" & vbCr & vbCr & "Name"

    objMessage.AddAttachment filename

    'This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP 
    server.
    'Normally you will only change the server name or IP.
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

    'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = 
    "word"

    'Server port (typically 25)
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

    'End remote SMTP server configuration section==

    objMessage.Send



    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the docmd.outputto you have to open the excelfile, freeze at the cell you want, save and close the file, as example:

```
Function FreezeMe(strfile As String)

Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(strfile)
Set ws = wb.Sheets("sheet1")         ' change to the name of your sheet

wb.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
ws.Range("a2").Select                ' change to the range you want to freeze 

wb.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
wb.Save
wb.Close


End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! One question: what exactly would I put in the argument in my Access macro for this function; it currently says: FreezeMe(<<strfile>>). It seemingly won't run unless I do that.

Comment: The name of the xlsx-file you have written to, so you could use your variable filename.

You could also copy the few lines of code to your function after the filename = ... Statement ans use filename instead of strfile.

Comment: I've edited my code in my original post to contain the recommendation you gave me after filename =; it's still throwing me an error. Can you see upon first glance if I'm doing something incorrectly? I appreciate your help

Comment: Which error? if the error occurs als "user defined type not defined" (our something like that - i have a german Version) in 
dim xl as Excel.worksheet
then you have to set the reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library (Tools->References)

P.S.: Add a wb.Close after the wb.save, too.

Comment: That was all I needed to do was add that library. Thank you for your help again!